# Functions and variable space with threading using clone

Tags: multithreading, memory, gcc, clone

I currently intend to implement threading using clone() and a question is, if I have all threads using the same memory space, with each function I call in a given thread, will each thread using a different part of memory when the same function is called, or do I do have todo something to ensure this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Each thread will be using the same memory map overall but a different, separate thread-local stack for function calls.  When different threads have called the same function (which itself lives at the same executable memory location), any local variables will not be shared, because they are allocated on the stack upon entry into the function / as needed, and each thread has its own stack by default.

References to any static/global memory (i.e., anything not allocated on the thread-local stack, such as globals or references to the heap or `mmap` memory regions passed to / visible to a thread after calling `clone`, and in general, the full memory map and process context itself) will, of course, be shared and subject to the usual host of multithreading issues (i.e., synchronization of shared state).

Note that you have to setup this thread-local stack space yourself before calling `clone`.  From the manpage:

> The `child_stack` argument specifies the location of the stack used by
>   the child process.  Since the child and calling process may share
>   memory, it is not possible for the child process to execute in the
>   same stack as the calling process.  The calling process must therefore
>   set up memory space for the child stack and pass a pointer to this
>   space to `clone()`.
>   Stacks grow downward on all processors that run Linux (except the HP
>   PA processors), so `child_stack` usually points to the topmost address
>   of the memory space set up for the child stack.

The `child_stack` parameter is the second argument to `clone`.  It's the responsibility of the caller (i.e., the parent thread) to ensure that each child thread created via `clone` receives a separate and non-overlapping chunk of memory for its stack.

Note that allocating and setting-up this thread-local stack memory region is not at all simple.  Ensure that your allocations are page-aligned (start address is on a 4K boundary), a multiple of the page size (4K), amply-sized (if you only have a few threads, 2MB is safe), and ideally contains a "guard" section following the usable space.  The stack guard is some number of pages with no access privileges-- no reading, no writing-- following the main stack region to guard the rest of the virtual memory address space should a thread dynamically exceed its stack size (e.g., with a bunch of recursion or functions with very large temporary buffers as local variables) and try to continue to grow into the stack guard region, which will fail-early as the thread will be served a SIGSEGV right away rather than insidiously corrupting.  The stack guard is technically optional.  You should probably be using `mmap` to allocate your stacks, although `posix_memalign` would do as well.

All that said, I've got to ask: why try to implement threading with `clone` to start? There are some very challenging problems here, and the POSIX threading library has solved them (in a portable way as well).  If it's the fine-grained control of `clone` you want, then checkout the `pthread_attr_*` functions; they pretty much cover every non-obscure use case (such as allowing you to allocate your own stack if you like-- from the previous discussion, I'd think you wouldn't).  The very performant, general Linux implementation, amongst other things, fully wraps `clone` and a large variety of other heinous system calls relevant to threading-- many of which do not even have C library wrappers and must be called via `syscall`. It all depends upon what you want to do.

Comment: Thank for that, to be honest, I am coming the conclusion that I should just use pthreads, but yes, part of motivation is control, and generally I have a preference to writing my own functions for things really, such as threads where I am able todo.