# How can one implement pthread_detach on Linux?

Tags: linux, pthreads

`pthread_detach` marks a thread so that when it terminates, its resources are automatically released without requiring the parent thread to call `pthread_join`. How can it do this? From the perspective of Linux in particular, there are two resources in particular I am curious about:

1. As an implementation detail, I would expect that if a `wait` system call is not performed on the terminated thread, then the thread would become a zombie. I assume that the pthread library's solution to this problem does not involve `SIGCHLD`, because (I think) it still works regardless of what action the program has specified to occur when `SIGCHLD` is received.
2. Threads are created using the `clone` system call. The caller must allocate memory to serve as the child thread's stack area before calling `clone`. [Elsewhere on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13504123/481267), it was recommended that the caller use `mmap` to allocate the stack for the child. How can the stack be unmapped after the thread exits?

It seems to me that `pthread_detach` must somehow provide solutions to both of these problems, otherwise, a program that spawns and detaches many threads would eventually lose the ability to continue spawning new threads, even though the detached threads may have terminated already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pthreads library (on Linux, NPTL) provides a wrapper around lower-level primitives such as `clone(2)`.  When a thread is created with `pthread_create`, the function passed to `clone` is a wrapper function.  That function allocates the stack and stores that information plus any other metadata into a structure, then calls the user-provided start function.  When the user-provided start function returns, cleanup happens.  Finally, an internal function called `__exit_thread` is called to make a system call to exit the thread.

When such a thread is detached, it still returns from the user-provided start function and calls the cleanup code as before, except the stack and metadata is freed as part of this since there is nobody waiting for this thread to complete.  This would normally be handled by `pthread_join`.

If a thread is killed or exits without having run, then the cleanup is handled by the next `pthread_create` call, which will call any cleanup handlers yet to be run.

The reason a `SIGCHLD` is not sent to the parent nor is `wait(2)` required is because the `CLONE_THREAD` flag to `clone(2)` is used.  The manual page says the following about this flag:

> A new thread created with CLONE_THREAD has the same parent process as the process that made the clone call (i.e., like CLONE_PARENT), so that calls to getppid(2) return the same value for all of the threads in a thread group.  When a CLONE_THREAD thread terminates, the thread that created it is not sent a SIGCHLD (or other termination) signal; nor can the status of such a thread be obtained using wait(2).  (The thread is said to be detached.)

As you noted, this is required for the expected POSIX semantics to occur.

Comment: But then what happens if the thread terminates abnormally, e.g., by `tgkill`? Then the `__exit_thread` function would not be called, right?

Comment: Correct.  Then the creation of the next thread runs cleanup.

Comment: That makes sense. Can you edit this into your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: How does abnormal thread termination get detected?